# Recuperar double GridView javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El siguiente código apunta al evento `change` de un `textbox` (columna 3).

Quiero recuperar el valor en un `asp:TextBox` de un `GridView` (Columna 5)

```
$("#<%=GridEdos.ClientID%> [id*='txtBox']").change(function () {


     var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
     var ValEsta = $("td:eq(5)", tr).html(); 

     $("td:eq(4) span", tr).html(parseFloat($(this).val()) + ValEsta); 
});
```

La idea es sumar ambos valores y poner la suma de ambos. Sin embargo lo que obtengo es (espero ser claro) el valor de la columna 3 seguido de **una caja de texto** y adentro el valor que yo busco.

¿Si en `var ValEsta` recibo la caja de texto, como apunto al valor adentro de esa caja?.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de la variable `ValEsta`? coloca: `console.log(ValEsta);` y actualiza tu pregunta con el resultado obtenido. No comrepndo si lo que obtienes un valor o código HTML...

Comment: He cargado una imagen para mostrar que es lo que obtengo en lugar de obtener 40000500 que sería la suma, obtengo lo que aparece en "Despues"    src="gesegap.com/02Images/IMG.png".  Revisa el link porfavor

Comment: Kate, no veo ningún enlace de la imagen que mencionas en tu comentario; pero puedes agregar una imagen a tu pregunta de la siguiente manera: Selecciona el enlace "editar" - que se encuentra debajo de tu pregunta; luego, pulsa sobre el icono en forma de imagen que se encuentra en las herramientas de edición. En cuanto a tu comentario, si estás obteniendo un valor diferente al que deseas, puede ser que no estás apuntando al elemento HTML correcto. Ejemplo: cambia `var ValEsta = $("td:eq(5)", tr).html();` a `var ValEsta = $("td:eq(6)", tr).html();`

Comment: Añadí la imagen, no sabía hacerlo, gracias por ese tip. Pues como resultado de la suma obtengo lo que está en el recuadro rojo. ¿A qué crees que se deba?

Comment: Kate, es porque en realidad estás modificando el código HTML y no los valores. He creado una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente quedó como:

```
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

            //Recibo los objetos hijos que en este caso es un input
            var ValEsta = $("td:eq(5)", tr).children();

            //Recibo el valor y además reemplazo de manera recursiva todas las comas
            var txt = ValEsta.val().replace(/,/g, '');

            //Convierto a numero para poder sumarlos
            $("td:eq(4) span", tr).html(parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat(txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de la imagen indica que en realidad la variable `ValEsta` y la línea:

```
$("td:eq(4) span", tr).html(parseFloat($(this).val()) + ValEsta);
```

En realidad están obteniendo el *código HTML* y no los *valores* de los campos de texto.

Para obtener los valores de los campos de texto puedes usar:

```
// Obtener el valor de un campo de texto.
var miNumero = $('#txt_num').val();
```

Fuente: **[Respuesta a Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903284/4092887)**.

---

En tu código, prueba cambiando `html` a `val`; así:

```
$("#<%=GridEdos.ClientID%> [id*='txtBox']").change(function () {

     var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
     var ValEsta = $("td:eq(5)", tr).val();

     // Revisa en la consola de tu navegador el resultado.
     console.log(ValEsta); 
     console.log($("td:eq(4) span", tr).val());

     $("td:eq(4) span", tr).val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + ValEsta); 
});
```

Sin embargo, revisa que estés obteniendo el campo de texto.

Comment: No funcionó, si coloco val no me muestra la caja de texto ni el valor del mismo.

Comment: @Kate2707, por favor actualiza tu pregunta, creo que estás usando jquery y javascript. = java y javascript son dos lenguajes de programación diferentes. He actualizado mi respuesta. En tu navegador, presiona la tecla F12. Revisa la pestaña "console" y revisa los resultados.

Comment: Lamento los errores, soy un poco nueva, muchas gracias por el apoyo, he dado con la respuesta, la pondré por aquí.

Comment: @Kate2707 que bueno que hayas encontrado la respuesta. No hay de que lamentarse y Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. Saludos.